Visualizing Drawdown
I want to replicate the image below:

Does anyone have an idea how to do this in Python. To be specific; I am only having problems plotting the blue shade and the blue lines.

You can use matplotlibs fill_between.

I’m voting to close this because it is pretty much a programming question.
